# Windows 7 files have been deleted

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and like it, but there is a program I urgently need to use which doesn't work with DWM. Because DWM is impossible to disable in Windows 8 and up, I desperately need to get back to Windows 7. I knew I could go back to Win 7 within a 30 day period of upgrading and I am still within that period, but when I try and go back I get this message which says "We're sorry, but you can't go back. The files we need to take you to a previous version of Windows were deleted." I know for a fact I never touched my Windows or Windows.old folders.

I am absolutely desperate to go back to Windows 7. I will do ANYTHING to go back, even if I cannot upgrade to Windows 10 after. I would prefer not to pirate anything, but will use it as an absolute last resort.

This is a Custom PC. I don't have the Windows 7 DVD, but I do have my product key.

Comment: What program? Someone might know a workaround.

Comment: I've already checked. To be more specific the program is QuArK Army Knife. Technically the software renderer works but the far distance is unbearable then, and OpenGL requires that DWM is disabled to work correctly or I get this strange effect where the back of a cube seems to be going through the front of it. The issue is known but hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen someone he received this message, even when he had not deleted any folders. To tell the truth, until now, I have not found the way or the detailed steps to solve this problems, only some suggestions.

The following conditions may cause this:

Create a new account

Remove the $Windows.~BT and $Windows.~WS folders required by the system to perform the rollback operation.

Tried other reduction / restore factory settings function

Remove the verification file installation

After a month of upgrading to Windows 10

But your case should not be the same with these reason the above.

**Suggestions:**

Check:
If you used third party junk remover and it inadvertently deleted these folders or if you manually deleted them, If you use the media creation tool to download a second copy and make a bootable USB. The second copy apparently replaces the original windows upgrade folder (~BT) too.

Suggestions by thewindowsclub:

[We’re sorry, but you can’t go back. The files we need to take you back were removed](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/were-sorry-but-you-cant-go-back-windows-10)

Run Windows Update Troubleshooter

Run sfc /scannow

Run DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth.

If it’s been over a month, you’ll no longer see this option. Windows 10 appears to automatically remove the old Windows installation files after a month to free up space. Then you can only have the opportunity to downgrade by rollback tool like [Easeus System GoBack](http://www.easeus.com/system-go-back/). The downgrade tool is released by EaseUS, he claims to do exactly that.

But The program is only of use if you run it prior to upgrading to Windows 10.

Only can give you these suggestions, if I find a specific way, i will edit this.

Comment: I guess this answer will have to do for now, and I wasn't expecting much more. I was hoping for some manual way of going back using an ISO file and some technique, but from what I can tell at this point it's just not possible. I didn't tamper with the WIndows.BT folder, in fact it's still there, but I suppose maybe AVG got rid of something important within it.